# Multiple file uploads in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I just want to know how to upload multiple files in octobercms at front-end
there is no tutorial,

I am using

```
<input name="posting-image" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

and then got only the last uploaded image

```
$posting->posting->image=Input::file('posting-image');
$posting->save();
```

how can I retrieve all images ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey if you want multiple images you need to use `array[] in name of image/file`

so you need to write your input as

```
<input name="posting-image[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<!-- you need to add this ^ array brackets after name -->
```

`posting-image[]` so now this can hold multiple images rather then just last image.

now you can use simply this to get multiple image at php side

```
$posting->posting->image= Input::file('posting-image');
// this will return you array of uploaded files
$posting->save();
```

if any problem please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik Satasiya

Comment: Hey Hardik, i want to know possibility of fileupload field with pivot form, is it doable? 

I am trying it but it seems not working. You are expert in core flows of OctoberCMS. Please message me on this.

Comment: Hi Dear, if you explain to me what is schema and where you need to put that file I can understand it and help you better :)